# Nonnull violation detection in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nullable

I have some code like this where I declare an object with nonnull properties

```
@interface HelloObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong,nonnull) NSString *foo;
@property (nonatomic,strong,nonnull) NSString *bar;

-(instancetype _Nullable)initWithJson:(nonnull NSDictionary*)json;
@end
```

and then to initialize the object from the JSON I make use this code:

```
-(instancetype _Nullable)initWithJson:(nonnull NSDictionary*)json
{
    if( (self = [super init]) ) {
        _bar = json[@"bar"];
        _foo = json[@"foo"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

The server may have sent me malformed JSON. For example, the "foo" field might be missing. It would be easy enough to check for nil and return nil, but I have a lot of this code and it would be inelegant and error prone.

Is there a *easy and elegant* way to check to see if an object violates its nonnull declarations at runtime? For example, I don't want to write code like this:

```
        barX = json[@"bar"];
        if (barX) {
            _bar = barX;
        } else {
            return nil;
        }
```

That's ugly and boilerplate (and therefore prone to error). I'd much rather have something like:

```
    if (![self ValidForNonNulls]) {
        return nil;
    }
```

but I can't think of a way to write ValidForNonNulls for a general object.

Comment: Could you clarify the manner in which you'd ideally conduct this test?  I am confused by your express desire to both "check [for violations] at runtime" while *not* wanting to "check for nil and return nil" as this seems to me to be a contradiction.

Comment: Clarified in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that trying to work around the need to test for `nil` is practical in Objective-C.

If I were having to verify many such incoming terms, and I needed to check them for validity or return `nil`, then I would rewrite my `initWithJson` method to check, with a category to keep the code clean and readable.

```
- (instancetype _Nullable)initWithJSON:(nonnull NSDictionary *)json
{
    if ( (self = [super init]) ) {
        if ( ![json hasValuesForKeys:@[@"foo", @"bar"]] ) {
            //Consider logging this as an error
            return nil;
        }

        _bar = json[@"bar"];
        _foo = json[@"foo"];
    }

    return self;
}

...

@interface NSDictionary (hasValuesForKeys)
- (BOOL)hasValuesForKeys:(NSArray *)keys;
@end

@implementation

- (BOOL)hasValuesForKeys:(NSArray *)keys
{
    for (NSString *key in keys) {
        if ( !self[key] || [self[key] isEqual:[NSNull null]] ) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}

@end
```

You could make more specific tests for each value if you need to validate whether they are `NSNumber` for example.